# D3 animation does not updated

Tags: jquery, html, d3.js, dom-events

I created one page to plot some data with D3.js. It works well in my desktop and under the device debugging mode of Chrome. However, **when I open the page with my iPhone, the SVG cannot be updated**.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('#btn1').on('click touchstart', function(){
        update("current");
    });
    ... ...
});
```

I used the `chrome://inspect` function in the ISO Chrome to have done some tests and found out that the update function are called successfully, and the **touchstart event bound successfully**.

So now my question is why the **D3 does not update the SVG in my [web page](https://www.qubotong.com/covid19/vis)?**

One part of my updating function are shown as the code below:

```
function update(typestr) 
{
   line.datum(data)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("stroke", getTypeData(null, typestr, _DATATYPES.COLOR))
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.d3date) })
            .y(function(d) { 
                return y(getTypeData(d, typestr, _DATATYPES.DATAVALUE))})
        )
......
}
```

Comment: For the second question, did you consider using a search engine to find the answer?

Comment: @Mehdi I do found the way to debug for Chrome on my desktop. It works well as well. I'm now very confusing about why it does not work for my iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I sovled this problem. Turns out that somehow the lifetime of functions is not performing as I thought.

In my update function, I use a function called `getTypeData(null, typestr, _DATATYPES.COLOR)` to switch among different types of data. **This function should defined inside the update function**. Otherwise, the mobile browser will terminate this update function.

Also, the **line** variable should also be select again by

```
var line = svg.selectAll("path.lineTest")
```

inside the update function.

Any articles about the difference of lifetimes of variables are welcome to add.